# Loading times in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have noticed the following fact: It takes a page much longer to load immediately after I "start" the code with `npm run dev` command, then in all subsequent "page refreshes".

Looking at the network tab in Chrome DevTools I found out, that first load is 4 times slower, than the second one.

**First load**
[image]

**Second load**
[image]

Why is that happening? And are there any ways to speed the things up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js compiles lazy in `development` mode: when the first request is made to the endpoint. Subsequent requests are served by compiled code. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/608

In `production` mode all resources have to be compiled upfront with `next build` for the best performance, try it yourself: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-cli#production